# SeekBar programmatically

Tags: android, seekbar

I am creating a **SeekBar** programmatically like this :

```
SeekBar seekBar = new SeekBar(this);
seekBar.setMax(15);
seekBar.setIndeterminate(true);
seekBar.setMinimumWidth(200);

ShapeDrawable thumb = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());

thumb.getPaint().setColor(0x00FF00);
thumb.setIntrinsicHeight(80);
thumb.setIntrinsicWidth(30);

seekBar.setThumb(thumb);
seekBar.setProgress(1);
```

But what all I am able to see is a small **SeekBar**.
What might be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try with the following code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.OvalShape;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class Sample2 extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SeekBar seekBar = new SeekBar(this);
        seekBar.setMax(15);
//      seekBar.setIndeterminate(true);

        ShapeDrawable thumb = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());

        thumb.setIntrinsicHeight(80);
        thumb.setIntrinsicWidth(30);
        seekBar.setThumb(thumb);
        seekBar.setProgress(1);
        seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        seekBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(200, 50);
        seekBar.setLayoutParams(lp);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(".....111.......");

            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(".....222.......");
            }

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(".....333......."+arg1);
            }
        });
        setContentView(seekBar);
    }
}
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: I can see the seeBar but I am unable to seek it.

Comment: Hi Stone, Now check my code. I have added listener to seek bar. now you can seek th seekbar

Comment: SeekBar seekBar = new SeekBar(this);
        seekBar.setMax(15);
        ShapeDrawable thumb = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        thumb.setIntrinsicHeight(100);
        thumb.setIntrinsicWidth(40);
        seekBar.setThumb(thumb);
        seekBar.setProgress(1);
        seekBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(400, 20);
        seekBar.setLayoutParams(lp);

Comment: How can I change the color of seekbar which I have progressed. eg the color of seekbar which has progressed is green and the part which is not is blue. Are you getting what I am trying to say?

Comment: see http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/08/change-background-color-by-seekbar.html

Comment: how to change the image for seekbar volume controling.when volume is ZERO mute icon other wise normal thumb icon

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out `seekBar.setIndeterminate(true);` that may be having an undesired effect.

Comment: How about `seekbar.setProgressDrawable( getResources().getDrawable( android.R.drawable.progress_horizontal );`

Comment: Yes. I tried giving the value 400 but width didn't change. I also tried LayoutParams.fill_parent. That didn't work too.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with your View hierarchy. What parent are you adding this control to? If the parent is set to WRAP_CONTENT then you'll see this kind of behaviour.

Comment: I am adding it to a linear layout. But I am not setting any layout params for it. Now after the change you suggested, I am able to see the space 400 wide but seekbar is not visible.

Comment: I just got it work fine. I am editing my question with correct code in it.

Comment: SeekBar seekBar = new SeekBar(this);
        seekBar.setMax(15);
        ShapeDrawable thumb = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        thumb.setIntrinsicHeight(100);
        thumb.setIntrinsicWidth(40);
        seekBar.setThumb(thumb);
        seekBar.setProgress(1);
        seekBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(400, 20);
        seekBar.setLayoutParams(lp);