# Android sliders programmatically

Tags: android

[image]> i want to implement slider bar in my application  without using xml. i try to search using google but not able to get any sample code.how to create slider bar in android, pls guide me,

Comment: What is "slider bar"? Do you mean SeekBar?

Comment: @Demand : yes. i want to use seekbar programmatically like aboce picture.

Comment: and what is your problem? What have you tried?

Comment: @Demand : i tried this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343116/seekbar-programmatically but not able to get like above picture.

Comment: WHat is it that isn't like what you want?  What isn't working?  You aren't being clear enough to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, it uses the built in SeekBar. The onProgressChanged is passed the location of the progress and an integer between the value 0-100 when it is changed.

```
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class SeekBarExample extends Activity {
    LinearLayout ll;
    SeekBar sBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        sBar = new SeekBar(this);
        SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener abc = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                //Executed when progress is changed
                System.out.println(progress);
            }
        };
        sBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(abc);
        LayoutParams sBarLayParams=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(sBar,sBarLayParams);
        setContentView(ll);
        }
}
```