# Set seekbar theme programmatically

Tags: android, android-theme, android-seekbar

I have a SeekBar with ticks:

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"/>
```

Is it possible to set theme programmatically? I mean if I want to keep ticks I can set the theme using  @style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete" otherwise I can do nothing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343116/seekbar-programmatically

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I can't see the answer there.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I can see to set the style attribute programmatically is in the constructor of `SeekBar`. Perhaps when you want to change the style programmatically implement this code.

```
SeekBar oldSeek = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = oldSeek.getLayoutParams();
int id = oldSeek.getId();
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) oldSeek.getParent();
SeekBar newSeek = new SeekBar(context, null, R.style.YOUR_NEW_STYLE);
newSeek.setLayoutParams(lp);
newSeek.setId(id);
parent.removeView(oldSeek);
parent.addView(newSeek);
```

You gather all the attributes of you initial `SeekBar`, create a new `SeekBar` with the desired new style and then remove the old `SeekBar` and add the new one.